# Fix element position in responsive pages

Tags: html, css

I have a html page that has many tags. The ones I am trying to style with css are `article` and `nav`.

```
<html>
<body>
    <article>(many article inside ths article)</article> 
    (many tags here) 
    <nav></nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to style some tags but I don't know css good. First I have to show the text only in 60% of my page so i did this and it works:

```
body{width: 60%;}
```

Then I had to show my nav on the left side of my principal article but it also must be 20% width of my page content (and my article the rest of the width).  I managed to do it like this but I have the next problem:

```
article ~ nav{position: fixed;left: 0px;top: 7%; width: 20%;}
```

The problem is when I resize my browser. The position of my nav is changing. I need it to remain fixed on the left of my article with a width of 20%. I am allowed to change only the css file. The html tags have no classes or id. I managed to do it with bootstrap but I need to do it without the bootstrap grid system.

Comment: With `top` set to a percentage, it will move up and down as the window size changes.

Comment: The `nav` is always on the left. Where is the issue? And of course it is overlapping the article text, but I don't know your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment below, then you should try this:

use the child selector `>` to select the tags that are a direct descendant of the body tag and add the `padding-left` to those.

```
body {position: relative;}
body > article, body > div {padding-left: 40%;}
nav {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 20%}
```

Comment: yes but I am allowed to change only the css file. The html tags have no classes or id atributes. I can't create a wrapper container and set an id in my html page

Comment: If this worked for you, could you click the tick next to my answer to mark it as correct please!

Answer (score 1):

It is something like this what you want?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                position: relative;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 60%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            nav {
                position: absolute;
                width: 20%;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background: blue;
            }
            article {
                position: absolute;
                width: 80%;
                left: 20%;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>(many article inside ths article)</article> 
    (many tags here) 
        <nav></nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes but  I am allowed to change only the css file. The html tags have no classes or id atributes. I can't create a wrapper container in my html page :(

Comment: Ok, have a look to that code (it didn't changed very much...)